# Date returns wrong

Tags: templating

I'm trying to sort entries on a page by a custom field, by date and time. I have sample data over several entries with different dates and times, and where I want it to show the date of the event, it shows "January 1, 2016" (with the correct time) for all events, instead of the date and time of the `eventStartDT` field.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('events').order('eventStartDT').limit(4) %}

    <div class="uk-width-large-1-3 uk-width-medium-1-2 uk-width-small-1-1 uk-container-center" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
        <a class="fpcLink" href="#">
            <div class="frontPageContent">
                <div class="fpcInner">
                    <span class="text-content"><span><i class="uk-icon-calendar uk-icon-large"></i><h3>EXPLORE</h3></span></span>
                </div>

                <div class="fpcLower">
                    <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3><p>{{ entry.eventStartDT | date('F n, Y - g:i A') }}</p><p class="uk-text-small">{{ entry.shortEventDescription }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I feel supremely stupid.

I put

```
date('F n, Y - g:i A')
```

Should be

```
date('F j, Y - g:i A')
```

Total brain fart. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Thanks for following up with an answer, Dustin! Don't forget to accept it.